# Capture the first part of URL in address bar and store in variable

Tags: jquery

I would like to capture the first part of the current URL in the address bar up to a certain point and store in a variable.

For example if the current URL address in the address bar is:

```
http://website.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/Sites-DE-Site/Sites-DE-Library/de_DE/v1389214044701/campaign_summer_2014_projects/14-03-12s_men/img/436x768/look1.png
```

I would like to store the part up to `campaign_summer_2014_projects` so what would be stored would be:

```
http://website.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/Sites-DE-Site/Sites-DE-Library/de_DE/v1389214044701/
```

is this possible, it needs to be dynamic, as the that first could be on different domains.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use `.split` on occurence of campaign_summer_2014_projects .try this:

```
url="http://website.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/Sites-DE-Site/Sites-DE-Library/de_DE/v1389214044701/campaign_summer_2014_projects/14-03-12s_men/img/436x768/look1.png";

 alert(url.split(/campaign_summer_2014_projects(.+)?/)[0]);
```

**[working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NL3U9/1/)**

Comment: This works but it includes the name of the html at the end like so: test.html how can I remove that too?

Comment: @user1937021: i did not get you.can you elaborate ??

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstPart = window.location.href.match(/(.*)campaign_summer_2014_projects/)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = window.location.href;
var url_part = url.split('campaign_summer_2014_projects')[0];
```